# How to disable read-only attribute for multiple Excel files on sharepoint?

Tags: excel, sharepoint, vba

I am trying to run a VBA code on multiple Excel 2016 files which are located on a Sharepoint folder. The problem is that the files are set as "locked for editing", therefore the VBA code crashes while trying to run. 
So is there a way to change these attributes for all these files so the VBA code can run successfully?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The file are "Lock" because someone else work on this files. This files are checkout in the sharepoint (all update are disable except for the user who working on it).

- Soluiton 1: ask to the owner of your files to checkin documents
- Solution 2:  If you are SharePoint Admin, you can checkin documents for other people
- Solution 3: if you can run powerhsell or c# you can use the SharePoint API to chekin the file. Or Remove the lock on your file

When you run vba of your excel file, you must open document in edit mode, the edit mode is disable by the "lock" (checkout) of sharepoint. It's not a VBA or Excel problem